# How to get all data array after looping in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, swift4.2

I make struct to add data, here is my struct:

```
struct data {
    var documentCode: String?
    var attachmentSize: String?
    var applicationType: String?
    var fileExtension: String?
    var file64: String
    var contentType: String
}
```

Then I add some String to struct:

```
let allData = [
        data(documentCode: "1", attachmentSize: "2", applicationType: "3", fileExtension: "4", file64: "5", contentType: "6"),
        data(documentCode: "a", attachmentSize: "b", applicationType: "c", fileExtension: "d", file64: "e", contentType: "f"),
        data(documentCode: "12", attachmentSize: "2", applicationType: "3", fileExtension: "4", file64: "5", contentType: "6")
    
    ]
```

Here is my looping, I make `var datas = [String: String]()` to add data to dictionary:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var datas = [String: String]()

    let allData = [
        data(documentCode: "1", attachmentSize: "2", applicationType: "3", fileExtension: "4", file64: "5", contentType: "6"),
        data(documentCode: "a", attachmentSize: "b", applicationType: "c", fileExtension: "d", file64: "e", contentType: "f"),
        data(documentCode: "12", attachmentSize: "2", applicationType: "3", fileExtension: "4", file64: "5", contentType: "6")
    
    ]
    
    for checkData in allData{

        datas = ["documentCode": checkData.documentCode, "applicationType": checkData.applicationType, "attachmentSize": checkData.attachmentSize, "fileExtension": checkData.fileExtension, "file64": checkData.file64, "contentType": checkData.contentType] as! [String : String]

        print(datas)
    }
    
    print(datas)
}
```

When I print datas inside looping I get data like this:

```
   ["file64": "5", "applicationType": "3", "attachmentSize": "2", "fileExtension": "4", "contentType": "6", "documentCode": "1"]
   ["file64": "e", "fileExtension": "d", "documentCode": "a", "attachmentSize": "b", "contentType": "f", "applicationType": "c"]
   ["documentCode": "12", "fileExtension": "4", "attachmentSize": "2", "applicationType": "3", "file64": "5", "contentType": "6"]
```

But when I print outside looping I get only last index array:

```
   ["file64": "5", "applicationType": "3", "attachmentSize": "2", "fileExtension": "4", "contentType": "6", "documentCode": "1"]
```

How can I get `allData` array outside looping?

Comment: can you try `dump(datas)` ??

Comment: First of all you should name all your structures starting with an uppercase letter . Second choose a better name for your structure because Data it is already a native Swift type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created just Dictionary. what you need to create "Array of Dictionary".
Updated Code:-

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var datas = [[String: String]]()

    let allData = [
        data(documentCode: "1", attachmentSize: "2", applicationType: "3", fileExtension: "4", file64: "5", contentType: "6"),
        data(documentCode: "a", attachmentSize: "b", applicationType: "c", fileExtension: "d", file64: "e", contentType: "f"),
        data(documentCode: "12", attachmentSize: "2", applicationType: "3", fileExtension: "4", file64: "5", contentType: "6")
    
    ]
    
    for checkData in allData{
        datas.append(["documentCode": checkData.documentCode, "applicationType": checkData.applicationType, "attachmentSize": checkData.attachmentSize, "fileExtension": checkData.fileExtension, "file64": checkData.file64, "contentType": checkData.contentType] as! [String : String])

    }
    
    print(datas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it seems like you want `allData` so just `print(allData)`.

To explain your example, the last item set to `datas` would be your last index in your array being `["file64": "5", "applicationType": "3", "attachmentSize": "2", "fileExtension": "4", "contentType": "6", "documentCode": "1"]`.

If `datas` was a variable located INSIDE the loop, the print statement of `print(datas)` would not even work.

I believe you just want `print(allData)`.

Comment: Looks like OP should have declared datas as an array of dictionaries and he should be appending a new element at each iteration

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, he just wants access to ALL of his data points -- `how can i get alldata array outside looping?` -- so he literally just wants to `print(allData)`. I don't see how it could be concluded to an array of dictionaries - he only wants an array of his struct. Which he has - `allData`

Answer (score 0):

inside the loop you have updated the dictionary with same key, as a result you have got only one data in dictionary. To hold all the data you need to use array of dictionary.
You ca declare datas like :

```
var datas : [[String: String]] = []
```

then inside you can append in array loop:

```
for checkData in allData{

    let data = ["documentCode": checkData.documentCode, "applicationType": checkData.applicationType, "attachmentSize": checkData.attachmentSize, "fileExtension": checkData.fileExtension, "file64": checkData.file64, "contentType": checkData.contentType] as! [String : String]
    datas.append(data)
    
}
print(datas)
```